# Image hover overlay with text - text position

Tags: css, overlay

Good evening,
I am trying to make image hover overlay with text, but displayed text is always on the top of the image. I would like to display it in the middle of it.
I've tried padding etc, but it moved the overlay as well, that it covered also the free space below the image. Could you please help me, how to margin only text from top? Thank you!

EDIT: Or the best solution would be, if I could include another div with text only. Because I need to include text with html tags and it's not possible this way, via "content:"

http://jsfiddle.net/sL6bjebx/

Here is CSS code:

```
.image {
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.image img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:;
}
.image:after {
    content:'Here is some text..';
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height: 100%; max-height:100%;

    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.image:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle demo ?

Comment: Please read our [ask] page to help you write a great question.  Great questions tend to get great/quick responses from the community

Comment: @om. Here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/sL6bjebx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your overlay text is going to be a one liner then you can use line-height css property to make it vertically center aligned

```
.image:after {
    content:'Here is some text..';
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height: 100%; max-height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    line-height:300px;
}
```

and if not, then I will suggest to use another way to display the content.

such as `:before` just like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sL6bjebx/1/), Or you can use a `<p>` tag as well instead of the `:before` tag check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sL6bjebx/3/).

```
.image:after {
    content:'';
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height: 100%; max-height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    z-index:1
}
.image:before {
    content:'Here is some text..';
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height: 20px;
    top:0; left:0; right:0;
    bottom:0;
    opacity:0;
    margin:auto;
    z-index:2
}
.image:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
.image:hover:before {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! But could this be solved by another div or something, where would be possible to insert text with HTML tags? Something like
<div class="image"><img src="..."><p class="overlayText"><b>Here</b> is some text</p></div>
Because I need to insert there phone and email.. So I need to use at least <p> </p> and <a>.. But in the best case, I would like to insert phone and email icons before the text.. And it's impossible via used "content:...;"

Comment: @HSturma: check my updated answer. I have added another fiddle with the code. just like you said into your comment.

Comment: Thank you! But there is impossible to use <p> twice, like to have 2 rows on the image :( even if I expand "p" 's height

Comment: But <br> works..:) I should have tried it before.. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: @HSturma I did not understood what you want to say, but if you want multi liner text then you can have that in one `<p>` tag. and if you want multiple `<p>` tags still you can use my example, just change `<p>` tag with `<div>` and inside that div you can have multiple `<p>` tags. its very simple. there is nothing like impossible with HTML structuring, :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution with another div or something, where would be possible to insert text with HTML tags:

```css
.image {
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 317px;
    height: 317px;
    text-align: center;

}
.image img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:;
}
.image .overlayText {
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height: 100%; max-height:100%;
    line-height:317px;

    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  margin:0;
}
.image:hover > .overlayText {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="image">
   <img src="http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6v66lJ5K61r0taux.jpg">
   <p class="overlayText"><b>Here</b> is some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should simply add `line-height`

```css
.image {
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.image img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:;
}
.image:after {
    content:'Here is some text..';
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height: 100%; max-height:100%;
    line-height:317px;

    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.image:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image" style="width: 317px; height: 317px; text-align: center;">
    <img src="http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6v66lJ5K61r0taux.jpg"> 
</div>
```